# Can I type デュ without using the small letter modifier?

Tags: discussion, writing

I can type デュ on OS X by typing in "d e x y u", but if I try using "d y u" instead, I get ヂュ. Is there any way to get デュ without having to type in five letters like "d e x y u"?

Asked on meta because technology questions aren't allowed on main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be able to type it with `dhu`.  That works on most input methods, so it's worth a try.

Comment: Can confirm it works on OSX.